# I need repeat some piece of code everytime, when I get in main_activity android

Tags: android

Good day, I have one question, I always need refresh names in spinner, when I get in main_activity and I don't know how can I make it. Here is the piece of code, which I need repeat everytime when I get in main_activity:

```
    arrTblNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND  name!='android_metadata'", null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            while ( !c.isAfterLast() ) {
                arrTblNames.add( c.getString( c.getColumnIndex("name")) );
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }        

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
             android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrTblNames);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                selectedtable = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: Yes I have it in onCreate() but in the main activity I have method to delete table so when I call method delete table and it deletes table, so in spinner is still the name of table and I want refresh names in spinner after this method.

Comment: The problem is, that it refreshes names in spinner only after restart application and I need to make some method, which I call everytime when I get in main_activity and this method make this piece of code, but I dont know, how can I make this method and how can I call it :/

Comment: and how can I re-call the method, when I make modification in another activity?

Comment: do you have some tutorials or something where is it describe some more? Because I have never made any methods

Comment: thank you, but I still understand not so much what can I change on my code, can you be more accurately, what exactly I should add before the piece of code and with which exactly instruction can I call the method?